# Mongo: count the number of word occurrences in a set of documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a set of documents in Mongo.  Say:

```
[
    { summary:"This is good" },
    { summary:"This is bad" },
    { summary:"Something that is neither good nor bad" }
]
```

I'd like to count the number of occurrences of each word (case insensitive), then sort in descending order.  The result should be something like:

```
[
    "is": 3,
    "bad": 2,
    "good": 2,
    "this": 2,
    "neither": 1,
    "nor": 1,
    "something": 1,
    "that": 1
]
```

Any idea how to do this?  Aggregation framework would be preferred, as I understand it to some degree already :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[MapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/) might be a good fit that can process the documents on the server without doing manipulation on the client (as there isn't a feature to split a string on the DB server ([open issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6773)).

Start with the `map` function. In the example below (which likely needs to be more robust), each document is passed to the `map` function (as `this`). The code looks for the `summary` field and if it's there, lowercases it, splits on a space, and then emits a `1` for each word found.

```
var map = function() {  
    var summary = this.summary;
    if (summary) { 
        // quick lowercase to normalize per your requirements
        summary = summary.toLowerCase().split(" "); 
        for (var i = summary.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            // might want to remove punctuation, etc. here
            if (summary[i])  {      // make sure there's something
               emit(summary[i], 1); // store a 1 for each word
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Then, in the `reduce` function, it sums all of the results found by the `map` function and returns a discrete total for each word that was `emit`ted above.

```
var reduce = function( key, values ) {    
    var count = 0;    
    values.forEach(function(v) {            
        count +=v;    
    });
    return count;
}
```

Finally, execute the mapReduce:

```
> db.so.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: "word_count"})
```

The results with your sample data:

```
> db.word_count.find().sort({value:-1})
{ "_id" : "is", "value" : 3 }
{ "_id" : "bad", "value" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "good", "value" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "this", "value" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "neither", "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "or", "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "something", "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "that", "value" : 1 }
```

Comment: Wow... the map/reduce part of Mongo is a lot easier to understand than I feared.  Thanks for providing such a great answer!

Answer (score 7):

A basic MapReduce example

```
var m = function() {
    var words = this.summary.split(" ");
    if (words) {
        for(var i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
            emit(words[i].toLowerCase(), 1);
        }   
    }
}

var r = function(k, v) {
    return v.length;
};

db.collection.mapReduce(
    m, r, { out: { merge: "words_count" } }
)
```

This will insert word counts into a collection name words_count which you can sort (and index)

Note that it doesn't use stemming, omit punctuation, handles stop words etc.

Also note you can optimize the map function by accumulating repeating word(s) occurrences and emitting the count, not just 1

Comment: Thank you for the excellent response.  I'm in the difficult position of having to choose one "right" answer, and although your's works perfectly well, WiredPrairie's answer has comments and a little more explanation.  Thanks for taking the time to help me out!

Answer (score 4):

You can use #split.
Try Below query

```
db.summary.aggregate([
{ $project : { summary : { $split: ["$summary", " "] } } },
{ $unwind : "$summary" },
{ $group : { _id:  "$summary" , total : { "$sum" : 1 } } },
{ $sort : { total : -1 } }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question but since 4.2 this can be done with $regexFindAll now.

```
db.summaries.aggregate([
  {$project: {
    occurences: {
      $regexFindAll: {
        input: '$summary',
        regex: /\b\w+\b/, // match words
      }
    }
  }},
  {$unwind: '$occurences'},
  {$group: {
    _id: '$occurences.match', // group by each word
    totalOccurences: {
      $sum: 1 // add up total occurences
    }
  }},
  {$sort: {
    totalOccurences: -1
  }}
]);
```

This will output docs in the following format:

```
{
  _id: "matchedwordstring",
  totalOccurences: number
}
```