# Searching a document multiple times for a phrase or word

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Say I have the following collection containing the fields `username` and `message`:

```
{ 
    "username" : "bob", 
    "message" : "testing hello"
}
{ 
    "username" : "harry", 
    "message" : "hello hello"
}
{ 
    "username" : "harry", 
    "message" : "hi hello"
}
{ 
    "username" : "tom", 
    "message" : "hello there"
}
{ 
    "username" : "john", 
    "message" : "hey"
}

etc ...
```

I can use the following code to get the top 10 usernames for which the word "hello" occurs the most in their messages:

```
db.collection('collectionName').aggregate(
    { $match : { message: /hello/ } }, 
    { $group : { _id: '$username', count: { $sum: 1 } } }, 
    { $sort : { count : -1 } }, 
    { $limit : 10 }, 
function(err, results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```

This results in something like:

```
{ _id: 'harry', count: 2 },
{ _id: 'bob', count: 1 },
{ _id: 'tom', count: 1 }
```

My question - how do I search each document (or `message` field) multiple times to retrieve the total count of the word "hello", not just the number of documents which contain it at least once. The count for "harry" would then return 3 instead of 2. Thanks.

Comment: I think that the same question solved using MapReduce [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174591/mongo-count-the-number-of-word-occurences-in-a-set-of-documents

Comment: Wow.. I did not know you can do something like that with MongoDB. Thanks for linking that stack!