# MongoDB query array and summarize keywords

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I would like to query the sub-key of an array, extract keywords, and count them.

The words that I'd like to extract from are in "Title." When I applied the query filter, it shows that the field I need to query is `Reviews.0.Title`. But I have at least 200 elements inside the `Reviews` array.

How do I do this?

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("561c3ccc4c97f053753f1a78"), 
    "Reviews" : 
    [
        {
        "Ratings" : {
                 "Service" : "4", 
                 "Overall" : "5"
                    }, 
        "Location" : "MIS", 
        "Title" : "“Excellent and great”", 
        "Author" : "JDoe", 
        "ReviewID" : "1", 
        "Date" : "March 30, 2015"
        }, 
   {
    "Ratings" : {
                  "Service" : "4", 
                  "Overall" : "5"  
                 }, 
    "Location" : "WIS", 
    "Title" : "“Excellent and fantastic!”", 
    "Author" : "John Doe", 
    "ReviewID" : "2",  
    "Date" : "March 27, 2016"
   }
    ],

    "Info" : 
    {
    "Name" : "AA",
    "ID" : "0001"
     }
}

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("561c3ccc4c97f0ytu7289074"), 
    "Reviews" : 
    [
        {
         "Ratings" : {
                 "Service" : "4", 
                 "Overall" : "5"
                    }, 
         "Location" : "VEG", 
         "Title" : "“Not too bad”", 
         "Author" : "JDoe", 
         "ReviewID" : "3", 
         "Date" : "March 30, 2015"
        }, 
       {
        "Ratings" : {
                  "Service" : "4", 
                  "Overall" : "5"  
                 }, 
        "Location" : "NEV", 
        "Title" : "“Outstanding service”", 
        "Author" : "John Doe", 
        "ReviewID" : "4",  
        "Date" : "March 27, 2016"
       }
    ],

    "Info" : 
    {
     "Name" : "BB",
     "ID" : "0002"
    }
```

}

I would like to get the following output:

```
{ "_id" : "Excellent", "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "Great", "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "Location", "value" : 2 }
```

edited output with name:

```
{ "Name" : AA: "Excellent", "value" : 1 "Great", "value" : 1 }
{ "Name" : BB: "Great", "value" : 1 }
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the current query filter with your final expected output from the above document, for example?

Comment: @chridam i've edited the question to include the final output. i tried using map-reduce, but can't get the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a `mapReduce` solution that provides a functionality similar to what you are looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174591/mongo-count-the-number-of-word-occurences-in-a-set-of-documents)

I adjusted that solution and generated the following `mapReduce` query:

```
db.reviews.mapReduce(
// Map function
function () {
    if(this.Reviews) {
        this.Reviews.forEach(function(review) {
            if(review["Title"]) {
                // Remove all punctuation from the review title
                var titleNoPunctuation = review["Title"].replace(/[^\w\s?.]/g, "");

                // Transform all the review titles to lower case and split them into word tokens
                var titleTokens = titleNoPunctuation.toLowerCase().split(" ");

                titleTokens.forEach(function(word) {
                    emit(word, 1);
                });

            }
        });
    }
},

// Reduce function
function (key, values) {
    var counter = 0;

    values.forEach(function(value) {
        counter += value;
    });

    return counter;
},

// Output collection 
{ out: "word_count"});
```

The above query stores its results in a different collection, as specified in the `out` attribute, in this example `word_count`.

Thus, in order to fetch the result set returned by the `mapReduce` job, you need to run the following query on the `out` collection (`word_count`):

```
> db.word_count.find();
{ "_id" : "excellent", "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "great", "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "location", "value" : 2 }
```

Comment: thanks Vlad! that works really well. I am using MongoChef, and copied the functions for map and reduce separately.

Comment: can i run the entire script using intellishell? i tried, but the output is different.

Comment: I ran the query directly from the mongo shell. What is the output in your `word_count` collection? And what version of MongoDB are you running?

Comment: i am using the mongochef 3.3 core and mongod version: 3.2.10 (MMAPv1)

Comment: the output i get is this in JSON:

Comment: The output is this:  { 
    "result" : "word_count", 
    "timeMillis" : NumberInt(495), 
    "counts" : {
        "input" : NumberInt(10), 
        "emit" : NumberInt(4065), 
        "reduce" : NumberInt(373), 
        "output" : NumberInt(975)
    }, 
    "ok" : NumberInt(1)
}

Comment: Yes, that means that the actual results have been placed in a different collection, `word_count`. To see the actual results, you now need to run `db.word_count.find()` and you will have the actual results you are looking for.

Comment: thanks Vlad, now i understand. How do i change the mapreduce to get the name of the key that has the most number of these words? i  updated the question to include the collection (it has a name key).

Comment: @S.Ray That is the standard format that `mapReduce` jobs use when producing a result set. If you want to change the standard output format, you can modify the structure of the `mapReduce` result set. Here you can read more about this process: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416262/how-to-change-the-structure-of-mongodbs-map-reduce-results

Comment: Z Thanks, I'll try and change the output. Thanks a lot for your help!